# LocalStorage to sent to email via PHP from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to build a eCommerce/checkout system that is very bare bones, but I would like to take localStorage data and send it to PHP via jQuery or some other form (open to whatever is easiest). When the email was sent I received a '.' for 'productsInCart' and no text for 'totalCost'. I got the idea for this code from [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-get-localstorage-key-value-into-a-php-variable-If-so-how-can-we-do-it), but seems like I am missing something on the jQuery side of things.

**Relevant jQuery code (nested in a vanilla JS file):**

```
localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
// methods between
var orderDetails = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
var orderTotal = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

jQuery.post("checkout-handler.php", {orderDetails: value}, function(data) {
    
}).fail(function(){
    alert("Sorry, we messed up something on our end. Please try again.");
    // localStorage.clear() on fail so the user can go back and fix issue?
    // return user to previous page and show new alert?
});

jQuery.post("checkout-handler.php", {orderDetails: value}, function(data) {
    // do something with PHP
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('yikes');
});
```

**Relevant PHP code:**

```
$orderInfo = $_POST['orderDetails'];
$orderTotal = $_POST['orderTotal'];
// other variables needed are here
$body .= "".$name." ordered: ".$orderInfo. ". \r\n";
$body .= "Amount sent to paypal should be: ".$orderTotal. "\r\n";
//mail(....) is after
// HTML code to show user a confirmation message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you declared parameters but you never really used them:

```
var orderDetails = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
var orderTotal = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
```

in your jQuery it should be:

```
jQuery.post("checkout-handler.php", {orderDetails: orderDetails}, function(data) {
    
}).fail(function(){
    alert("Sorry, we messed up something on our end. Please try again.");
    // localStorage.clear() on fail so the user can go back and fix issue?
    // return user to previous page and show new alert?
});

jQuery.post("checkout-handler.php", {orderDetails: orderDetails}, function(data) {
    // do something with PHP
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('yikes');
});
```

You see I replaced `value` with `orderDetails`, because that holds your value.